# Rails: unable to escape after using content_for with raw

Tags: ruby-on-rails, escaping

In a helper method I have this:

```
content_for(:title, raw(page_title))
```

And in my view I have this after calling the helper method:

```
<%= h(content_for(:title)) %>
```

However when I do this, the h() does not HTML escape the content? I've also tried `content_for(:title).html_safe` and `html_escape(content_for(:title))` with no success.

I save the content as raw as I want to access the raw (unescaped) content in a separate view.
I'm on Rails 3.0.17.

Answer (score 1):

After some investigation, here's my conclusions: It's all about html_safe.

Let me explain with some code:

```
page_title.html_safe? #false
raw(page_title).html_safe? #true - that's all that raw does
content_for(:title, raw(page_title)) #associates :title with page_title, where page_title.html_safe? returns true
```

Now when the view calls the helper method here's what happens:

```
content_for(:title) #no escaping. Since page_title was stored and html_safe is true, conetnt_for will not escape
h(content_for(:title)) #no escaping. Since the last line returned a string where html_safe? returns true, this will also not escape.
<%= h(content_for(:title)) %> #no escaping. Same reason as above
```

In short, `raw` simply sets the `html_safe` attribute on the string/SafeBuffer. Escaping is performed only on strings where `string.html_safe?` returns `false`. Since the string returns `true` at each opportunity for escaping, the string is never escaped.

**Resolution:**

Create a new string through interpolation or concatenation - this will set html_safe to false again and the string will be escaped.

For more, check out this guide on [SafeBuffers](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/02/01/safebuffers-and-rails-3-0/) and read the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/SafeBuffer.html).